# Include a file and get his variables

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my ajax form validation I show an alert dialog with some text if the fields aren't correct.

```
$("#button").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.post("control.php", 
        $('#Form').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            switch (data) {
                TXT_1 = "Name is empty!";
                TXT_2 = "Age is empty !";
                TXT_2 += "Please set it";

                case "NOME_EMPTY":
                    $("#alert").dialog("open").html(TXT_1);
                    return false; 

                case "AGE_EMPTY":
                    $("#alert").dialog("open").html(TXT_2);
                    return false;
            }
        }
    );

    return false;
});
```

For me to obtain a more clean script, I'd like to put all the texts in a separate file.
It's possible to do? How could I include this file in my script and calls these variables `TXT_1`, `TXT_2`, etc? thanks

Comment: [i18next](http://i18next.com/) is your friend [even if you don't plan to make your website localizable].

Comment: You can simply declare the variables in another js file and include it before the above script.  I'd strongly recommend giving them better names though, which describe the content more meaningfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called `resources.js` and put the following in it...

```
TXT_1 = "Name is empty!";
TXT_2 = "Age is empty !";
TXT_2 += "Please set it";
```

Then add this to the `head` of your page...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources.js"></script>
```

Then remove the variable declarations from your original script...

```
$("#button").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.post("control.php", 
        $('#Form').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            switch (data) {

                case "NOME_EMPTY":
                    $("#alert").dialog("open").html(TXT_1);
                    return false; 

                case "AGE_EMPTY":
                    $("#alert").dialog("open").html(TXT_2);
                    return false;
            }
        }
    );

    return false;
});
```

Because the external js file was included before the above script it will have access to any global variables or methods that are in there.